# find adsense earning from different websites

Tags: google-adsense

I am going to add my Adsense code to one new website I've created recently.

The problem is how to find out which site earned what in final earning. I need to share the earning of second site with my partner. I can setup different channel to see what each site earned but the final earning may not be the same.

So how can I find out which site earned what in final earning page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google adsense has what it calls "[hosted domains](https://www.google.com/adsense/v3/app#myads-viewall-adunits/product=SELF_SERVICE_DOMAIN&view=ADUNITS)" which lets you see what domain is getting what traffic. In addtion, as you suggest, I set up separate channels for each of my domains. However, again as you say, these are estimates not the actual sum.